# Officejs: get All customXmlParts from document

Tags: office-js, cpu-word

I am using officeJS API to create word add-in. I have added CustomXMLParts into the document, but I'm not able to retrieve all available custom XML parts from the document. OfficeJs document does not provide any API to get all custom XML parts, we  can get those either by namespace or by id. But how we get all xml parts at a time? If anyone know the approach please provide the example.

Thanks In advance,
Pooja.

Answer (score 1):

How about looping through the namespaces and getting the CustomXMLParts for each namespace and pushing them all onto a single array?

That is, create an array of strings; the namespaces. Loop through the array. For each namespace in the array, search-by-namespace.

Comment: Actually i don'have any single namespace to retrieve the customXMLParts. I just want all the customXMLParts.

Answer (score 1):

Use the namespace `http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/metadata/properties`:

```
const NS = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/metadata/properties'
const { customXmlParts } = Office.context.document
customXmlParts.getByNamespaceAsync(NS, (result) => {
  // result.value contains the parts array
  const parts = result.value
  customXmlParts.getByIdAsync(parts[0].id, (result) => {
    const part = result.value
    part.getNodesAsync('*', (result) => {
      const nodes = result.value
      // do stuff wit hnodes
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Super minor, but I'm assuming you meant 'Office.context.document.customXmlParts.getByNamespaceAsync'